# Unable to access custodian's files and folders from admin account in OneDrive CSharp SDK

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding against the `OneDrive C# SDK` and I have successfully proofed out that I can reference a user's drive from another user's personal site.

Scenario:

I have an admin account and a custodian account, I can log in from my admin account and successfully pull back basic profile data from the custodian account by passing in the custodian's `Id`.

Call to pull back custodian basic info:

`Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Drive folder = await this.oneDriveClient.Drives[Custodian_ID].Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync();`

However, I am having some difficulty around trying to view all folders and files that are located on a custodian's account from an admin account.

*Not working*

Call to pull back custodian folder and files:

`Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Item test = await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[id].Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync();`

The value of `id` in the call to fetch custodians files and folder is `Microsoft.OneDrive.SDK.Drive.Owner.User.Id`

My question is how do I construct a call to access a custodian's files and folders?

Comment: so.... what is the ***question?***

Comment: @abelenky I have updated the SO post to include a question.

Answer (score 0):

After going back and reviewing the docs at [OneDrive docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm). I constructed the path as so:

`Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Item folder = await this.oneDriveClient.Drives[Custodian's Drive].Root.Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync(); //root folder`

Call for Items in Folder:

`Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Item folder = await this.oneDriveClient.Drives[Custodian's id].Items[folder.Children.Id].Request().Expand(expandedValue).GetAsync();`